# count dimensions in complex multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm not sure if this has been answered but I would like to know if there is a simple way I can count the dimensions of an array without recursively calling a function.

Here's an example of what my array may look like....

```
$a[0][1][2][3]=4;
$a[0][11][22]=33;
$a[0][111]=222;
$a[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7]=888;
$a[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]=999;
```

But my real array wont be necessarily numeric.

What I would like for output are the following values from the above example...

3,2,1,7, and 8

Can anyone point me to the right direction without requiring recursive function calls or extensive CPU usage?

---

UPDATE:

The reason why I asked that question is because I do have a large problem to tackle. I borrowed a function on the internet that actually processed my adjacency list into an array as follows after using the print_r() function:

```
Array
(
[Pint] => Array
    (
    [Beer] => Array
        (
        [Parent] => Pint
        )

    [Parent] => 
    )

[Into] => Array
    (
    [Running] => Array
        (
        [Group] => Array
            (
            [Girl] => Array
                (
                [Parent] => Group
                )

            [Guy] => Array
                (
                [Parent] => Group
                )

            [Parent] => Running
            )

        [Parent] => Into
        )

    [Parent] => 
    )

)
```

What I want to do is use the data in the array to form a sentence without using fixed numbers or names since the array names and values (other than the key Parent) change.

So in this array, I want to form the following sentences using the words and walking through the array:

Desired sentence 1. A Pint of Beer (I will add "A" and "of" later. Pint and Beer come from the array.)

Desired sentence 2. Girl and Guy in a group running into something ("and", "in a", and "something" are words i will add to the sentence later)

If there was a function like foreach that starts at the last dimension and works into the first, that may be helpful. The common thing about these sentences is that the last dimension is dealt with first and the first dimension is dealt with last.

Anyone have ideas to an answer?

P.S. I updated the other code to make the array as follows:

```
Array
(
[Girl] => Array
    (
    [Group] => Array
        (
        [Running] => Array
            (
            [Into] => 
            )

        )

    )

[Guy] => Array
    (
    [Group] => Array
        (
        [Running] => Array
            (
            [Into] => 
            )

        )

    )

[Beer] => Array
    (
    [Pint] => 
    )

)
```

Comment: First off $a[0] is 1 dimension, so $a[0][111] would be 2 dimensions not your guess of 1.

Comment: you're right.... I forgot to update that. I was thinking too hard on the foreach loop.

Comment: @MikeSt See my updated answer.. looking at your data the depth of recursion shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, heres a recursive solution anyway. It gives a count of whatever the deepest dimension is:

```
function count_array_dimensions($a, $count) {
    $max = $count;
    foreach($a as $e) {
        if(is_array($e)) {
            $current = count_array_dimensions($e, $count+1);
            if($current > $max) {
                $max = $current;
            }
        }
    }

    return $max;
}

//Usage:
$a[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]=999;

//Initialize with 0 instead of 1 for your counting scheme
echo count_array_dimensions($a, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're off-by-one in the dimensionality of all those arrays.  Your outputs should be 4, 3, 2, 8 and 9.  [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) is your best bet here, unfortunately.

Comment: OP specifically said "without requiring recursive function calls"

Comment: I understand that.  Specifically, he or she said "without requiring recursive function calls or extensive CPU usage" which leads me to believe they are under the mistaken impression that such an operation would be CPU intensive.  It might be for a particularly massive array.  The only way to do it without recursion would be to use a stack and a queue and that would be at least equally CPU-intensive.  Hence my answer that his or her "best bet" would be to  use the one-liner array_walk_recursive().  array_walk_recursive() doesn't iterate over empty array elements, so it might not work either.

Comment: It's not a one liner, they still need to actually count the dimensions with their callback. I'm pretty sure my solution works without recursion and without a stack or a queue.

Comment: It does not work in the following cases:  (1) The array has non-numeric indices.  (2) The array does not have a zero index.  (3) The array has a zero index with fewer sub-arrays than another index.